Müger: semisimplicity implies duals are two-sided
In Müger's Modular Categories , end of page 3, he claims that if a $k$-linear monoidal category which is object semisimple, with  absolutely simple monoidal unit satisfies that all objects have left and right duals, then semisimplicity implies that these duals are two-sided.
Could someone explain why this is the case?

It suffice to check the statement on simple objects. To do so, note that by left (respectively right) rigidity we get the following:
$$\operatorname{Hom}(X \otimes Y, \mathbb{1}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(X, Y^\ast)$$
and
$$\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{1}, X \otimes Y) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(^\ast Y, X)$$
In particular, if $X,Y$ are simple we have $N_{X,Y}^{\mathbb{1}} := \dim \operatorname{Hom}(X \otimes Y, \mathbb{1}) \leq 1$ and is non-zero if and only if $Y^\ast \cong X$ and similarly $N^{X,Y}_{\mathbb{1}} := \dim \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{1},X\otimes Y) \leq 1$ and is non-zero if and only if $^\ast Y \cong X$.
Since $N_{X,Y}^\mathbb{1} = N^{X,Y}_\mathbb{1}$, combining the two we get $^\ast Y  \cong Y^\ast$.
